# IBOutlet not showing in File's Owner/ IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, interface-builder, iboutlet

In my .h file I have this:

```
@interface {
UILabel *questionLabel_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
```

In my .mm file I have this:

```
@synthesize questionLabel = questionLabel_;
```

When I go to the xib file I see no evidence of questionLabel in the File Owner. Nor can I connect a UILabel by ctrl dragging to File Owner or First Responder.

It is though working with two UIButtons I have created.

Ideas?

Comment: No class name in your interface file?

Comment: In Inspector please check the class name is set or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set appropriate class of your `File's Owner.`

Open `Utilities -> Identity Inspector -> Custom Class -> Class -> Select your class`.

After that you will be able to set outlets.